# Calculating average of the rating field by applying filter on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTJwi.png)

I have added image here which shows different columns in a dataframe ,so basically i want to calculate average of rating field based on the value Drama which is present in genre field of the dataframe ,which means that I will calculate the average rating of rows containing Drama in genre field ,so how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the `rating` column contains lists, you can use `astype` to be able to use `str.contains` properly, and then evaluate the mean:

```
df[df['genre'].astype(str).str.contains('Drama')]['rating'].mean()
```